# Feed trainind data python layer (FCN CAFFE)

Tags: caffe, training-data

I'm new with caffe. I'm trying to train nyud-fcn32s-color-d from https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org. I don't understand how to manage the training data before the definition of solver and the training phase. I've downloaded nyud-v2 .mat dataset from http://cs.nyu.edu/~silberman/datasets/nyu_depth_v2.html, but I don't know how to feed it with the nyud_layer (python layer). Sorry for the question, I'm a newbie, it's important to me make this training so any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should add tou your train/val prototxt the python layer, defined as

```
layer {
  name: "color"
  type: "Python"
  top: "color"
  top: "hha"
  top: "label"
  python_param {
    module: "nyud_layers"
    layer: "NYUDSegDataLayer"
    param_str: "{\'tops\': [\'color\', \'hha\', \'label\'], \'seed\': 1337, \'nyud_dir\': \'../data/nyud\', \'split\': \'test\'}"
  }
}
```

And fill the correct params, as described [in the implementation](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/nyud_layers.py):

```
- nyud_dir: path to NYUDv2 dir
- split: train / val / test
- tops: list of tops to output from {color, depth, hha, label}
- randomize: load in random order (default: True)
- seed: seed for randomization (default: None / current time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I've uptated trainval.protoxt, I need to change something in the nyud_layer? And in the nyud_dir what I need? I have classes,train,val,trainval and test (.txt), I added nyu_depth_v2_labeled.mat, but I fail to create the solver with only this files.

Comment: You need to set nyud_dir to where you unzipped the NYUD dataset (for example, ../data/nyud) and select the list of the desired tops. Can you edit your question to include the solver.txt contents and the error you get?

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works with your indication. I have another question. At the moment I'm able to define the solver, but as I imagined, with my 2gb gpu, when I try to start the training solver.net.forward(), I have the cuda out of memory error. How can I manage the situation? there's a way with nyud_layer to reduce the batch size? In data/nyud/data I have depth, hha, images, raw depth folders with .png files (560x425): it will help me if I resize all this png to a lower size?

Comment: Looks like the batch size is already 1 - see reshape function in nyud_layers.py -
        # load data for tops and  reshape tops to fit (1 is the batch dim)    
I suggest to submit an issue in FCN's GitHub repo.

Comment: However the deploy prototxt might specify different batch_size. It's the first dimension in the input layer.